# Optimize a Delta table used to make queries that use GROUP BY

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

Working in a Delta table.
When it comes to optimising my delta table, I have learned a few things.

`Partition by:` Is beneficial when the column in which the partition is made is used in a "where" condition.
i.e In a previous step. Let's say this is table A

```
df.write.partitionBy("column_1").format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("path")
```

I will use the Delta table like this in the future.

```
%sql
select 
    colum1
    column2
    ...
from TableA
where column1 = "XX"
```

`Bloom Filters:` Are beneficial for joins between tables. Imagine column_1 is our id column ,so you will be use it in that way

```
%sql

CREATE BLOOMFILTER INDEX ON TABLE TableA FOR COLUMNS(column_1)
OPTIMIZE TableA  ZORDER BY (column_1)


select 
    colum1
    column2
    ...
from TableA a
INNER JOIN  TableB b
ON  a.column_1 = b.column_1
```

But how can I optimise a table where Group by queries are to be used and no optimisation techniques such as Partition By or Bloom Filter are applied ? i.e. the table will be used as follows

```
%sql
select 
   colum1
   column2
   ...
from TableA
group by (column1, column2)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OPTIMIZE ... ZORDER BY (column1, column2)` may help colocating related values  in smaller number of files, and make querying of data more efficient. (see [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#z-ordering-multi-dimensional-clustering))

Comment: How would `OPTIMIZE ZORDER BY` help with aggregation? I don't get it? And moreover I'm even saying it won't work. I'm fine with `OPTIMIZE` alone (but `ZORDER BY` not really).

Comment: `OPTIMIZE` optimizes file sizes too, which helps reduce I/O (number of reads from storage). See my ans below for link that will explain more.

Comment: yes, that's true

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `ZORDER` as suggested.

Few more things:

- You can also fine [tune the file sizes](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#tune-file-size).
- Apply compaction (`OPTIMIZE`) periodically, especially if you're streaming or dealing with small batch sizes. I guess this is implicit if you're using `ZORDER` as other post suggested.
- [Same page](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html) also has many other suggestions including specific ones if you're trying to improve interactive query performance.
- For interactive queries, also note that the ["SQL Warehouse"](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/admin/sql-endpoints.html) has it's Spark configuration set up for optimal interactive performance, which will be better than a general purpose cluster.